# Android guidelines: multi pane layouts

Tags: java, android

I have a screen with search options. Clicking an option has the effect of showing a dialog or redirecting to another screen, which is why I can't use the "Settings" application approach: showing the next screen on the right-side.

On a tablet, my screen looks like this:

[image]

Which is not very neat. I think we've all read the wooonderful design guidelines for Android, offering solutions only for the simplest problems, such as turning:

[image]

into:

[image]

I have found no guidelines for multi-pane layouts other than "add a list view and a details view in the same screen, yo". Should I split up my ListView into smaller ListViews (each section in a ListView)? are there other applications that do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of links here in a similar question:

[How many Activities vs Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363790/how-many-activities-vs-fragments/12364574)

Here are a few more:

- http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
- [Patterns when to use Activity Transition vs Dynamic Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718242/patterns-when-to-use-activity-transition-vs-dynamic-fragments)
- [Android - I need some clarifications of fragments vs activities and views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478233/android-need-some-clarifications-of-fragments-vs-activities-and-views)
- [Activities or fragments in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794784/activities-or-fragments-in-android)
- [Multiple fragments and activities interaction design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701208/multiple-fragments-and-activities-interaction-design)

Also, yes you can certainly split your ListViews into smaller ListViews.  Fragments should make this easier to maintain as well.

You might also look into the `ActionBar` tabs -- there is a lot of info here as well:

http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I believe, the easiest way would be to use Fragments. There is an example with very similar layout in [Pro Android 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430239301) book.

Comment: Using Fragments is nowhere close to the easiest way of doing.. anything. I was only asking from a functional point of view. Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you will find the Fragment class handy in this situation. More information here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: I know about Fragments. I'm not asking how to break up my listview, but I'm asking whether I should break it up.

Comment: I think you should. At least that's what I'd do if I were to support bigger screens. It makes better use of the screen estate.